# How do I unlock the surprise for advent calendar?

Tags: advent-calendar

I bought the Lego Friends 2016 Advent calendar. It says that I can unlock a surprise on 12/4, but I can't find where to unlock it....

Comment: Same here. I guess Lego forgot... my daughter is a bit distraught

Comment: Same for the German website. My little daughter is appalled to say the least. She made me check the site several times today...probably nobody was on duty on a sunday. Woudl be good to have it prominent on the frontpage of the website.

Comment: My daughter is very upset with the surprise. She was hoping for an ani animation or similar and 'just got stupid build stuff that I've already done'. She couldn't even find the link herself.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! Here is the link for the December 4th surprise:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170505135238/https://www.lego.com/en-us/friends/activities/downloads/2017-christmas-bi-1